# Which os is better for a webserver, ubuntu or debian or something else?

Tags: php, ubuntu, webserver, centos, debian

I want to set up a webserver and i was wondering which os i should choose. People tell me i should choose between centOS, ubuntu or debian.

Basically the server os has to be able to do the following:
- Run a php/mysql website that will be visited by approxamally 1000 visitors a day.
- Support a server with raid configuration.

Which OS is the best option, and what packages would you advice to install?

Comment: This question is subjective and StackOverflow is not the right place to ask it. You might be better off on ServerFault. Either way, the question is subjective, and Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat and CentOS among others all have their merits.

Comment: I regret to see that important decision-making question that have technical answer(s) was labelled as "subjective". If this question were open then someone could provide a well balanced answer highlighting technical differences between those distros. Please consider re-opening and just downvote those who failed to answer it properly.

Answer (score 3):

They are all usable options for that purpose - companies use all kinds of platforms and get more traffic than you mention. I've ran sites on a webserver using the following OS's and following webserver platforms.

- Windows - Apache HTTP Webserver
- Ubuntu - Apache 2 Webserver
- Debian - Apache 2 Webserver

centOS has an Apache webserver platform too:

http://www.abixalmon.com/2011/08/centos-web-server-with-latest-apache-php-and-mysql

Also, note that power to host more visitors is not necessarily OS-dependent so much as MACHINE dependent.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is personell preference, I have also used ubuntu so I stick with that as I like the package managers and how quick things get updated for it.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer Debian.

Ubuntu is based on Debian, so it is good too, but I like Debian.
Also CentOS is good server-side OS too.

There are no correct answer to your question, the choice of OS is limited by personal preferences.